Precision issues when converting double to float
JDK has a random method in ThreadLocalRandom:
nextDouble(startInclusive, endExclusive)

But no float version. Here I want to float version, this is my implementation:
public static float nextFloat(float startInclusive, float endExclusive) {
    return (float) nextDouble(startInclusive, endExclusive);
}

I know float number has precision issues when cast double to float. So, is it possible the result float value < startInclusive or >= endExclusive? And how to solve it?

ThreadLocalRandom does have nextFloat methods. What version of Java are you using?

@Sweeper no nextFloat(float startInclusive, float endExclusive), only nextFloat(). JDK8

Indeed your current implementation might output a float that is equal to endExclusive. Suppose next double returns d, which is less than endExclusive, but the closest value to d representable by a float could still be endExclusive.
In modern versions of the JDK, there exists nextFloat that takes a lower bound and upper bound. If you are on an older version, you can just take a look at how nextFloat in newer versions are implemented, and do the same thing yourself.
Using the code from RandomSupport.java in the main branch of OpenJDK, you can write such a helper:
public static float nextFloat(Random random, float origin, float bound) {
    if (!(Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY < origin && origin < bound &&
        bound < Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid range");
    }
    float r = random.nextFloat();
    if (bound - origin < Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
        r = r * (bound - origin) + origin;
    } else {
        float halfOrigin = 0.5f * origin;
        r = (r * (0.5f * bound - halfOrigin) + halfOrigin) * 2.0f;
    }
    if (r >= bound)
        r = Math.nextDown(bound);
    return r;
}

This uses the parameterless nextFloat, which existed for a long time. It returns a random float between 0 and 1 inclusive, and the code simply linearly maps that 0~1 range to the range we want. It is also possible for this process to generate a number greater than or equal to the upper bound, in which case the JDK seems to just use the greatest float that is smaller than bound (Math.nextDown).

Re “So endExclusive might become a larger value when converted to double”: This does not happen. The set of float values is a subset of the set of double values. Each float value is a double value, so converting a float value to a double value produces the original value; there is no change.

@EricPostpischil oh yeah I didn’t realise that. Thanks for pointing that out!
